# Where are all the Daedalian Key locations in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I'm trying to find all the Daedalian Keys to put onto the chest cabinet thing in my common room, but I'm struggling to find all of them.

Where can I find all of them? Does someone have a list of locations to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 16 Daedalian Keys in total.

Here's where you can find all of them:

### 1. ASTRONOMY TOWER

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - ASTRONOMY TOWER]

### 2. RHINOCEROS SKELETON

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - RHINOCEROS SKELETON]

### 3. CENTRAL HALL

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - CENTRAL HALL]

### 4. LIBRARY

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - LIBRARY]

### 5. UPPER CENTRAL HALL

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - UPPER CENTRAL HALL]

### 6. POTIONS CLASSROOM

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - POTIONS CLASSROOM]

### 7. NORTH HALL

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - NORTH HALL]

### 8. SLEEPING DRAGON

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - SLEEPING DRAGON]

### 9. NEAR THE MAP CHAMBER

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - NEAR THE MAP CHAMBER]

### 10. GRAND STAIRCASE

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - GRAND STAIRCASE]

### 11. ENTRANCE HALL

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - ENTRANCE HALL]

### 12. THE GREAT HALL

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - THE GREAT HALL]

### 13. QUAD COURTYARD

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - QUAD COURTYARD]

### 14. FACULTY TOWER

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - FACULTY TOWER]

### 15. ALSO FACULTY TOWER

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - ALSO FACULTY TOWER]

### 16. CLOCK TOWER

[image: DAEDALIAN KEY LOCATION IN HOGWARTS LEGACY - CLOCK TOWER]